# C# remove a full string from an array based on a substring

Tags: c#

Say I have an array of strings

`string[] my_array = { "XY:1234567;ZW:124", "XY:124252"};`

And a user inputs `string user_input = "1234567";`

how can I remove the entire string from `my_array`

so after remove `XY:1234567;ZQ:124` is removed based on the partial input

`my_array = { "XY:124252" };`

My first attempt:

```
string[] my_array = { "XY:12345678;ZW:124", "XY:124252" };
string user_input = "1234567";
if(my_array.Contains(user_input))
    Console.WriteLine("Inside");
else
    Console.WriteLine("Not Inside");
```

Outputted `Not Inside`

My second attempt:

```
string[] my_array = { "XY:12345678;ZW:124", "XY:124252" };
string user_input = "%1234567%"; // Tried % to do a partial string I think?
if(my_array.Contains(user_input))
    Console.WriteLine("Inside");
else
    Console.WriteLine("Not Inside");
```

Outputted `Not Inside`

Im out of ideas

Comment: `array.Contains` checks if the array contains the entire string. You want `array.Any(s => s.Contains(...))`.

Comment: How does 124 partially matches 1234567?

Comment: You shoul'd use my_array.Any(s => s.Contains(user_input))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need `String.Contains()`. Try like:

```
string[] my_array = { "XY:12345678;ZW:124", "XY:124252" };
string user_input = "1234567";
foreach( var item in my_array)
{
   if(item.Contains(user_input))
      Console.WriteLine("Inside");
   else
      Console.WriteLine("Not Inside");
}
```